# Object.create vs Spread syntax to avoid Mutation

Tags: javascript

Today, I've just had a healthy debate with a coworker over `Object.create()`. The case is as follow, to prevent mutations:

```js
// coworker
filters = Object.create(filters);
filters.formats = [...selectedFormats, ...otherFormats];
return filters;
```

```js
// me
return {
   ...filters,
   formats: [...selectedFormats, ...otherFormats]
}
```

We both understand `Object.create()` differs from `Spread` but I, personally, do not have intensive understanding about `Object.create()` as I rarely see it being used somewhere.

My questions:

1. Difference between the two block of code?
2. Performance?
3. Drawback?

Thanks

EDIT:
Assuming `filters` is an object that has some values in it

```js
filters = new ReportFilters();
filters.foo = 'bar';
filters.formats = [1, 2, 3];
```

Comment: [Have you checked the documentation for `Object.create()`?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: @Pointy I have. But debating with my coworker as well as reading the documentation do not draw a satisfied conclusion for me. That's why I go to StackOverflow.

Comment: @adiga Let's call those `newFilters` and `oldFilters`. `filters = Object.create(filters)` is to use the `oldFilters` to set the prototype of `newFilters` which allows us to mutate/set properties on `newFilters` without altering the same properties on `oldFilters` aka to avoid mutation.

Comment: `Object.create(filters)` creates a new object with the object referenced by `filters` as its prototype. It does not copy the properties from the `filters` object into that created object, so in that sense the two pieces of code are significantly different.

Comment: @Pointy we understand that. But in this specific case, he used `Object.create()` to avoid mutating the `formats` property on the `filters` which I would typically do with the `Spread` syntax. I'm looking for an explanation of why he would use it in this case. Apparently, by asking this question on SO, we both don't have enough understanding of both Spread and Object.create() to come to an agreement.

Comment: Your code copies *all* of the properties from `filters` into the new object. Including "foo", from your added sample code.

Comment: Spreading doesn't prevent mutation if the object has more then one level, [spreading doesn't create a deep clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider

```
let filters = {}
filters.foo = 'bar';
filters.formats = [1, 2, 3];

let A = Object.create(filters);
A.formats = [11,22,33];

let B = {...filters, formats: [11,22,33]}
```

This results in the following structure in memory:

[image]

Both A and B have properties `foo` and `formats`, the only difference is that `A.foo` is resolved via the prototype, i.e. it's not an "own" property. Depending on the code that processes the state, it might lead to problems, for example:

```
Object.keys(A) -> [formats]
Object.keys(B) -> [foo, formats]
```

The bottom line: your coworker's code eventually introduces some hard to follow problems without any real benefit. You're right and he/she is wrong. ;)

Comment: The visual makes it much clearer. Thanks. Mind if I ask how you got the visual? 

As far as I know, `Object.create()` is/was the old syntax that was used under the hood by `Class` syntax before modern JS Compilers support `Class` syntax directly. Your explanation stay in line with my thoughts but is there any Memory/Performance consideration for using either approach?

Comment: @ChauTran: if the object is huge, then `Object.create` is more memory friendly as it won't make a copy of it. But in most cases, the problems with `create` I've mentioned outweigh this little benefit.